# How to stop large float numbers from being output in exponential form (scientific notation) in R?

Tags: mysql, r, scientific-notation

I'm working with ID numbers such as: "868130240945684480", which are stored into a MySQL database.

Whenever I make a query with RMySQL, the output is as follows: ""8.681302e+17" and then R reads it as "868130200000000000", which is a totally different ID.

Is there anyway to avoid this?

Here is the query I make to retrieve my data:

```
require(RMySQL)
con <- dbConnect(MySQL(), user='xxx', password='xxx', dbname='xxx', host='xxx')
rs <- dbSendQuery(con, "select sprinklr_twitter.Tweet_Id from sprinklr_twitter
                 inner join twitter
                 on sprinklr_twitter.Tweet_id=twitter.Tweet_id")
Tweet_id<-fetch(rs, n=-1)
Tweet_id<-as.data.frame(Tweet_id)
```

Comment: Try `options(scipen=99)`

Comment: So is the ID MySQL type LargeInteger or something.?

Comment: The MySQL driver is noting that the ID is an integer, so it tries to interpret it as such. In this case, it is significantly larger than R's largest integer (`.Machine$integer.max`), so it converts to a `numeric`, likely losing accuracy. One way around this is to deal with it as `character` within R (with SQL's `CAST(...)`); since I don't see a way in RMySQL to override the column class, you may have to do all of it in SQL.

Comment: @YannisP. yes, it is an integer in MySQL

Comment: I think you better go with @r2evans' suggestion

Comment: Hi @r2evans! I changed the storage type from Integer to Varchar and it went perfect. Thank you so much